# Normal map vector

Tags: normal-map

Recently while working with normal maps i discovered something interesting:

Normal map that I baked using Blender cycles:
[image]

Length of the normal vectors contained in the normal map:
[image]

Length of the normal vectors contained in the normal map divided by 2:
[image]

As it happens, the normal vectors in normal maps are not normalized but instead have a specific length depending on which direction it is facing.

I do have vague knowledge of how normal maps roughly work, e.g. RGB represent XYZ coordinates with 0.5;0.5;1 being neutral, but  apart from that I don't know anything about the actual calculations of when the normal map is created and used.

Can somebody please explain how tangent space normals are calculated?

Why are the resulting normal vectors not normalized?

Comment: What exactly is shown in the second two pictures?

Comment: Btw, [source code](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/139a4b6a844f6c6ae4c5bbd3c7799c91def7de35/intern/cycles/kernel/osl/shaders/node_normal_map.osl) for normal mapping (easy to read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: The answer turns out to be a combination of 3 and 5 below.  (5 was added in this edit.)  As made plain by excellent conversation with @scurest, Blender does not orthonormalize its tangent space, and we shouldn't expect unit vectors out of its normal map bakes.  They are often very close to unit vectors; it depends on the rate of change of the normal across the face.  Blender's treatment of this is not by-the-book, and creates problems for which I've submitted a bug report, but it is not unique either (I tested on xnormal, and it doesn't use orthonormal tangent space either; I've posted some questions regarding how other software handles it, but have no replies as of yet, and it's esoteric enough that basic internet research isn't any use.)

Let's try it out.  We'll bake a simple normal map, from a cube to an enclosing UV sphere, and see what our normals look like:

[image]

To a reasonable precision, it looks good.  None of my normals are shorter than 0.99 and none of them are longer than 1.01.  We shouldn't expect much more precision from 8 bit-per-channel color than that.

This image was generated with a single sample bake, but repeating the bake with 64 samples shows no difference.

So what am I doing different from you?  I can't say, because I don't have access to all of the details of your bake or your analysis material.  Here are some potential differences:

1. You weren't doing a selected to active bake, but instead baking from normals on a single object, which themselves weren't normalized.
2. You weren't baking and reading your normal map as non-color data.
3. You weren't remapping your normal map from the 0,1 range (which is necessary for almost all image formats) to the -1,1 range (which is the space necessary to represent the full range of normalized vectors.)
4. You were using texture filtering, by using "Linear" instead of "Closest" in your image texture node, which means that the actual color you were reading from the normal map wasn't a single texel, but was instead a box-blurred combination of several texels.
5. You're using different meshes, and something about the meshes I chose happens to minimize the issue.

Comment: You can't in general expect the RGB values to be a unit length vector (after remapping) though, that only happens if the (N, T, B) vectors are orthonormal. That should be true at the corners of a tri, but in the middle when interpolating it isn't guaranteed anymore. That's also why the normal mapping node normalizes its output.

Comment: @scurest Normal mapping techniques I've seen set the tangent to be at right angles to the normal, and then generate the binormal from the cross-product, guaranteeing orthonormality.  Blender doesn't do that?

Comment: It does, but It it only computes them at poly corners. On the poly interior, the normal and tangent are linearly interpolated from the corners, just like UVs, vertex colors, etc. and there's no guarantee they will be orthonormal just because they were at the corners. (B is computed at each point from the cross product of the interpolated N and T.)

Comment: @scurest So, normalized interpolated normal, normalized interpolated per-face tangent, normalized interpolated per-face binormal?  Doesn't seem smart to me, but I think it may explain some issues with normal maps that I've seen (and so maybe allow me to make some bug reports.)  Do you happen to know that this is true for both bake and rendering?  I believe there are differences between the two, as seen most easily by giving Suzanne a 0.5,0.5,1 normal map and then baking normals, giving differences apparent both in the baked image and in the render.

Comment: The interpolated N and T aren't normalized (so B isn't either), AFAICT. There's no reason to since it normalizes after linearly combining them. Why is that not smart, how else would you do it? I don't know how the baking works. My whole understanding is based off the source code I linked above.

Comment: @scurest You don't have to normalize early, just eventually.  But unit length is of little help if you don't have valid (orthogonal) basis vectors.  I'd do this from sample normal, b = normalize(cross(n, t)); t = cross(n, b).  Or whatever order for the cross, I always screw that up.  There's just so little you can do with invalid (not orthogonal) basis vecs-- you have vecs that are potentially impossible to represent in float range, and most of your library is built around the assumption of orthogonal basis vecs.

Comment: I don't see why that's better. Using the interpolated non-orthogonal vectors is cheaper at run time at the cost of being more expensive at bake time (finding coordinates in non-orthogonal basis is solving a linear system), which is the tradeoff you generally want to be making. What do you mean "vecs that are potentially impossible to represent in float range"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136300/discussion-between-nathan-and-scurest).

Comment: Sorry to interrupt your discussion but I do have a few questions: Firstly you said, that I need to remap the color channels of the normal map from a 0,1 range to a -1,1. I assume that I need to do that for the R and G channels (X and Y as coordinates). Now have read that there are two kinds of normal maps: The first kind of normal map uses a 0,1 range in the B channel to represent the Z coordinate (which I think is what Blender uses), while the other kind uses a 0,0.5 range in the B channel to represent the Z coordinate (which is stated in Wikipedia).

Comment: Secondly you said that remapping the normal map is necessary for most image formats. Are there image formats where Blender it isn't necessary? Aren't all normal maps created equally no matter the image format?

Comment: Lastly after I have remapped the RGB channels to their correct range is that it? Are those then the vectors, which when converted from tangent space to global space are my shading normals?

Comment: Blender remaps even Blue channel from 0,1 to -1,1.  I've never heard of mapping B from 0,1 to 0,1, and WP offers in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping : "Z:  0 to -1 :  Blue:  128 to 255" so I'm not sure what you're reading (although WP isn't great source, I myself have corrected a lot of bad info on that exact page, it gets drowned with beginning modders.)  Some image formats (.exr, certain .png formats) can represent negative numbers, and it would be possible to set things up to use those straight, but it's never done; it's always remapped.

Comment: "Are those then the vectors, which when converted from tangent space to global space are my shading normals?"  They are usually normalized afterwards (because you *do* want filtering, and because 8 bit color doesn't have precision to guarantee normality like floats do.)  But the idea is, yes, those remapped colors are your exact, tangent-space, rendering normals.  (Engines agreeing on exactly how to figure out what tangent space *is* for a particular sample is another matter.)

Comment: I am moving to the discussion chat cause Stackexchange tells me to do so...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136315/discussion-between-tempdev-nova-and-nathan).

Comment: Note that there is room for individual developers to iterate on this.  B 0,1 -> 0,1 is not unreasonable, I've just never heard of it done.  I have read about some developers modifying their normal maps to take advantage of the characteristics of filtering with different miplevels to create effects that they liked, so their normal colors were not intended to represent their literal tangent space normals-- filtering expectations were built into their images.

Comment: @scurest I tested, then made a bug report at https://developer.blender.org/T98175 .  I realized orthogonality is important for the same reason: constant shear is not a problem, but shear that varies with deformation is (and deformation is why we use tangent space.)  Thank you very much for your conversation; without it, I probably would never have developed my thoughts beyond "I've got a bad feeling about this Chewie."

Comment: Ok so to put everything straight: If I want to create a normal map using unit normal vectors that are already in tangent space I just remap from -1,1 to 0,1 and when I want to get the normal vectors in tangent space from a normal map I just remap from 0,1 to -1,1?

Comment: Yup, that's right.  Although be aware that "tangent space" is something different in different applications; the bug report I mentioned in my comment to scurest might make it more clear how different applications can calculate tangent space differently.  Blender's tangent space does not necessarily have unit length (or uniformly scaled) basis vectors, so if you normalize(1,0,1) you're not usually going to end up with a 45 degree angle from the normal.